# Live Reload refresh after 6s, and sometimes planted

Tags: javascript, html, css, livereload

Do you know if there is a solution for livereload function properly? Because for one week, it no longer works, or almost: (

The refresh occurs after 6s, it's very long, too long. Before, I had an error message about a js file, it was pretty weird.

Do you have a solution or an alternative to livereload?

Thank you to you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(yourFunction, timeout)
```

timeout in ms

Comment: Hi guys, i've question about the ms, it's minutes ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is one solution. Ajax.

**Edited**

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

This will run some code every 6s. Just store this code to the head of document.

```
var timer = null;
function loader(){
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
        return;
    }
    timer = window.setInterval(function(){
      // DO SOME CODE
    }, 6000);
}

window.onload = function() {
    loader();
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FK452/1/

And this will load page `boo.php` to `<div id="content"> </div>`. You can access var `json` from `boo.php` by `$_POST` -> `$_POST['json']`, `$_POST['second']`:

```
$.post('boo.php', {json: "value", second: "val"}, function(html){
  $("#content").html(html);
});
```